# dpkg: error processing mfc8500lpr:i386 (--remove)

Tags: 12.04, package-management, uninstall

I uninstalled this package with synaptic but it does not appear to have been completely removed.  I used autoremove and the result is below.  Reviewed several help requests but non seemed to work.

Can someone let me know what might work?

```
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done 
The following packages will be REMOVED: 
  language-pack-kde-en language-pack-kde-en-base mfc8500lpr:i386 
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 3 to remove and 0 not upgraded. 
1 not fully installed or removed. 
After this operation, 3,388 kB disk space will be freed. 
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y 
(Reading database ... 422194 files and directories currently installed.) 
Removing mfc8500lpr:i386 ... 
/var/lib/dpkg/info/mfc8500lpr.postrm: 3: /var/lib/dpkg/info/mfc8500lpr.postrm: /etc/init.d/lpd: not found 
dpkg: error processing mfc8500lpr:i386 (--remove): 
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 127 
Removing language-pack-kde-en-base ... 
Removing language-pack-kde-en ... 
Processing triggers for software-center ... 
INFO:softwarecenter.db.update:no translation information in database needed 
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ... 
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf.index... 
Errors were encountered while processing: 
 mfc8500lpr:i386 
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

---

Output requested

```
cupswrappermfc8500:i386                1.0.2-1                                 Brother MFC8500 CUPS wrapper driver
rc  dmraid                                 1.0.0.rc16-4.1ubuntu8                   Device-Mapper Software RAID support tool
rc  fbreader                               0.12.10dfsg-6                           e-book reader
rc  firstboot-video                        2.3                                     Plays a video at firstboot.
rc  kde-l10n-engb                          4:4.8.5-0ubuntu0.1                      British English (engb) localization for KDE
rc  kpartx-boot                            0.4.9-3ubuntu5                          Provides kpartx during boot
rc  language-pack-kde-en-base              1:12.04+20130128                        KDE translations for language English
rc  libdebconfclient0                      0.158ubuntu1                            Debian Configuration Management System (C-implementation library)
rc  libdebian-installer4                   0.79ubuntu2.1                           Library of common debian-installer functions
rc  libdmraid1.0.0.rc16                    1.0.0.rc16-4.1ubuntu8                   Device-Mapper Software RAID support tool - shared library
rc  libept1.4.12                           1.0.6~exp1ubuntu1                       High-level library for managing Debian package information
rc  liblinebreak2                          2.1-1                                   line breaking library for Unicode (shared library)
rc  libubuntuoneui-3.0-1                   3.0.1-0ubuntu1                          Ubuntu One widget library
rc  libzlcore0.12                          0.12.10dfsg-6                           ZLibrary cross-platform development library (shared library)
rc  libzltext0.12                          0.12.10dfsg-6                           ZLibrary text model/viewer part (shared library)
rc  oem-config                             2.10.20                                 Perform end-user configuration after initial OEM installation
rc  oem-config-gtk                         2.10.20                                 GTK+ frontend for end-user post-OEM-install configuration
rc  oobe-dim-disable                       1.0                                     Disables screen dimming.
rc  pdfedit                                0.4.5-2                                 Editor for manipulating PDF documents
rc  synaptic                               0.75.9ubuntu1                           Graphical package manager
rc  ubuntu-recovery-bootloader             0.3.35yongkang5                         Bootloader images for Ubuntu's factory process
rc  user-setup                             1.42ubuntu3
```

Comment: You have to use `purge` in order to remove it completely. I guess you have some residual packages.. Edit your question and post the output of this command: `sudo dpkg -l | grep -e "^rc" -e "^iU"`. Reply..

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the package tries to restart lpd service, witch is not there in the standard ubuntu installation. Try to run

> sudo ln -s /etc/init.d/cups /etc/init.d/lpd

before removing the package, do the uninstall and then run

> sudo rm /etc/init.d/lpd

to remove the link.

Comment: First command came back with  ln: failed to create symbolic link `./lpd': File exists

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

and

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

the problem of a broken package still exist the solution is to edit the dpkg status file manually.

```
sudo nano /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Locate the corrupt package(mfc8500lpr.postrm), and remove the whole block of information about it and save the file.

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-all [deb file path]
```

That is `mfc8500lpr:i386` file  path.